# Error handling in Scala

Tags: scala, error-handling, functional-programming

Suppose I have a function `foo`

```scala
def foo(a: A): B = ...
```

The function may fail with one of a few errors: `FooError1`, `FooError2`, and `FooError3`.

Suppose I don't want exceptions. So, I define a base error class `FooError`, with a few derived error classes and return `Either[FooError, B]` from `foo`.

```scala
case class FooError(a: A)
case class FooError1(override a: A) extends FooError(a)
case class FooError2(override a: A) extends FooError(a)
case class FooError3(override a: A) extends FooError(a)

def foo(a: A): Either[FooError, B] = ...
```

Does it make sense ?

It looks like too much code for every single function. Can  it be simplified ?

Comment: **Why** don't you want exceptions? If you want to postpone exception handling, you could always wrap the result in a `Try`. Any other reasons?

Comment: Let's assume I don't want exceptions just for aesthetic reasons.

Comment: Fair enough. However, since aesthetics are subjective, the question doesn't seem to be suited for SO in this context.

Comment: I am not asking about aesthetics :) I am asking if my example makes sense _assuming_ I don't use exceptions.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato BTW, could you give an answer _with_ exceptions ?

Comment: But then the assumption is due to *aesthetic* reasons, which brings us back to square one, IMHO. And sure, I can try, but what is the question in this case?

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato The question is: Suppose `foo` may fail with with one of `FooError1`, `FooError2`, and `FooError3`. How would you define `foo` in Scala ? You can use exceptions, `Try`, `Either` or any other thing you find appropriate.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there's still too many free variables for me to provide a helpful answer. Least I can do is say that @tuxdna 's answer is the closest to the general form of what I would implement, given the need to possibly deffer exceptions.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Thank you. I will think over it again and probably rephrase the question soon.

Comment: No problem :). I'll keep a lookout for it.

Answer (score 2):

I think this deserves a use of `Try`:

```
  type A = Int
  type B = String
  class FooError(val a: A) extends Throwable
  class FooError1(a: A) extends FooError(a)
  class FooError2(a: A) extends FooError(a)
  class FooError3(a: A) extends FooError(a)

  def foo(a: A): Try[B] = {
    val r = scala.util.Random
    val i = r.nextInt(20)
    Try {
      i match {
        case it if (1 to 3).contains(i) => throw new FooError1(1)
        case it if (4 to 6).contains(i) => throw new FooError2(1)
        case it if (7 to 9).contains(i) => throw new FooError3(1)
        case _ => "value" + a
      }
    }
  }                                               //> foo: (a: playground.A)scala.util.Try[playground.B]

  (1 to 5) foreach { x =>
    foo(x) match {
     case Success(x) => println(x)
     case Failure(t) => // error ignored
    }                                             //> value1
                                                  //| value4
                                                  //| value5
  }
```

Infact you can do away with all those classes, and simply throw a one single exception type with an error code.

```
  type A = Int
  type B = String
  case class FooError(val a: A) extends Throwable

  def foo(a: A): Try[B] = {
    val r = scala.util.Random
    val i = r.nextInt(20)
    Try {
      i match {
        case it if (1 to 3).contains(i) => throw new FooError(1)
        case it if (4 to 6).contains(i) => throw new FooError(2)
        case it if (7 to 9).contains(i) => throw new FooError(3)
        case _ => "value" + a
      }
    }
  }                                               //> foo: (a: play.A)scala.util.Try[play.B]

  (1 to 5) foreach { x =>
    foo(x) match {
      case Success(x) => println(x)
      case Failure(t) => t match {
       case FooError(code) => println("Error code was "+code)
      }
    }                                             //> Error code was 1
                                                  //| value2
                                                  //| Error code was 2
                                                  //| value4
                                                  //| value5
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `case class FooError(a: A)` by a `sealed trait FooError(a:A)`.

This way you could easily use a `match` expression and the compiler will tell you if you are missing a case.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before:

```
import language._
import util._
package object either {
  type Ok = Int
  type Result = Either[Error, Ok]
  implicit def badResult(e: Error): Result = Left(e)
  implicit def okResult(i: Ok): Result = Right(i)
}
package either {
  sealed trait Error { def info: String }
  case class BadInfo(info: String) extends Error

  class Typical {
    def f(): Result = BadInfo("oops")
    def g(): Result = 7
  }
}
```